# Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I get the following error if I run the PowerShell script below:Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I read several post on this site and other sites but al of them are more then 3 years old and not the solution of my problem.

The script was working very well, but from last Tuesday the powershell script give this exception. Nothing changed.
I try to run the script on the differt computer, but with the same result.
If I use an other user the error is still there.
SharePoint has no problem reported and I can log in to SharePoint via the browser.

I hope you can help me. Thanks for helping!

````
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

    #Bind to site collection
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SharePointUri)
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, $SecurePassword)
    $Context.Credentials = $Credentials

    #Retrieve list
    $List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocumentLibrary)
    $Context.Load($List.RootFolder)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery();```
````

Comment: Are you sure the credentials you are using here have not expired, had its password changed or something similar? 401 almost always means there is something wrong with the credential.

Comment: 401 in this context could well be an SSL issue.  I'm not familiar with these modules or sharepoint for that matter, but if you're confident in the credentials I'd look at SSL/TLS configuration.  For example, make sure the right versions are being supported on the client & server.

Comment: @Cbsch, Yes I check the credentials. If I said, I can login via the browser. I tried several accounts. All with the same issue.

Comment: @Steven, I will check this tomorrow with our infra people.The url is https, but I don't now if we can handle this because we use SharePoint online. TLS is maybe a good option. I let you know. thanks.

Comment: I have seen Powershell break on some sites when they disable older SSL/TLS versions. Making sure Powershell uses Tls1.2 has worked in such cases. Try adding this before any of the Sharepoint stuff: `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls12"`

Comment: @Cbsch I've used the same technique in URL monitoring scripts.  I often use an app called IISCryto to analyze which protocols and suites are enabled that may help if you need to take it that far.  Recently, I had an intermittent issue with an SQL query.  it was caused by windows patches on Windows 2016 that wasn't available to Windows 2012.  The patched changed the way some key exchanges were calculated.  Used IISCrypto to disable affected suites on the client to resolve the issue.  Sorry if TMI, hope it helps.

Comment: @Cbsch, Thanks. TLS is not working.

Comment: @Steven,  I will check IISCrypto. I let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with the SharePoint PNP module.
https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell